# When and why should I use CleanUp in mvvmlight

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm implementing a new windows application with MVVM Light and a doubt has emerged.

When should I use the cleanup method and why should I use?

Comment: The creator outlined the intended use for `Cleanup` in this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963151/cleanup-vs-disposebool-in-mvvm-light

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651420/mvvm-light-icleanup-and-messenger-unregister-in-vb-net <-- this was more what I was looking for! thanks anyway :)